# ASP.Net Core application can't find Microsoft.ApplicationBlocks.Data assembly

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, .net-core

I am building a new ASP.Net Core 2.0 application (targeting .net core 2.0) and it needs to reference a legacy .Net Framework 4.6 class library, which in turn uses Microsoft.ApplicationBlocks.Data. When I run the application, the very first time my application tries to call a static function from the class library it immediately throws the exception below:

> FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly
>   'Microsoft.ApplicationBlocks.Data, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=null'. The system cannot find the file specified.

I've checked the bin\Debug\netcoreapp2.0 folder where the app is running from and the dll is there. The dll appears to be identical to the one in the nuget package in the packages folder.

This is causing me a lot of problems and the class library uses ApplicationBlocks.Data a lot, I *really* don't want to rewrite huge swathes of the class library at this point to get it running with Asp.net core. This is the first step of a migration from framework to core and so the class library will likely be ported to core eventually but the company doesn't have the resources to be able to make all the changes at once.

Any help / suggestions / pointers would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What framework does your app target? Is it full framework or are you using .Net Core? (note: this is different from using ASP.Net Core)

Comment: @DavidG The application is targeting .net core 2.0. I forgot that you can target the framework with a asp.net core app. I've added the detail to the question.

Comment: The [`Microsoft.ApplicationBlocks.Data`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.ApplicationBlocks.Data/) package doesn't target .Net Standard so you can't go from .Net Core to that library.

Comment: However, relying on a library that is 4 years old and isn't supported any more, perhaps you should consider changing things?

Comment: @DavidG - I thought that you could call .Net Framework assemblies from .Net Core even if they weren't .Net Standard compatible. Am I misunderstanding this?

Comment: The intention is to get rid of this library in the mid to long-term but given that this is the first step in modernizing an application that's currently using aspx, ActiveX and even a bit of classic ASP and COM+, changing everything at once is not an option. There are literally thousands of references to Microsoft.ApplicationBlocks.Data and updating them all, including testing (manually, there's very little automated testing) would be a massive undertaking.

Comment: Well since you've started a new project, this is the best opportunity to build in automated testing! As for the 1000's of references, how hard would it be to re-engineer the library instead of your app? Having said that, that library looks a lot like an poor-mans ORM, so why not look at Entity Framework? I'm sure that would make your development a lot faster anyway.

Comment: The intention is to add automated testing while reengineering. It comes down to limited resources and commercial requirements to get new stuff out to customers quickly, it's just not possible to reengineer everything at once.
Looks as though we're going to need to go to Asp.Net and Entity Framework Core on .Net Framework as a stepping stone rather than going straight to .Net Core and getting more of the re-engineering done before making the full switch.
Thanks for your help @DavidG